# Are there expressive assertions in Scala?

Tags: scala, groovy

I've used Groovy for a while, one of the things I loved from there was the expressiveness that can be in test assertions, for example, this code:

```
def actual = [name: [firstName: "Elvis", lastName: "Presley"], age: 42]
def expected = [name: [firstName: "Elvis", lastName: "Costello"], age: 42]

assert actual.name.lastName == expected.name.lastName
​
```

Will have the next output:

```
Assertion failed: 

assert actual.name.lastName == expected.name.lastName
       |      |    |        |  |        |    |
       |      |    'Presley'|  |        |    'Costello'
       |      |             |  |        ['firstName':'Elvis', 'lastName':'Costello']
       |      |             |  ['name':['firstName':'Elvis', 'lastName':'Costello'], 'age':42]
       |      |             false
       |      ['firstName':'Elvis', 'lastName':'Presley']
       ['name':['firstName':'Elvis', 'lastName':'Presley'], 'age':42]

    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:4)
```

As you can see it shows the results of the navigation.

Is there something like this for Scala?

Comment: **ScalaTest** tries to do something similar, but it doesn't always works well given the complexity of the language.

Comment: I found what I wanted to do in https://diffx-scala.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ (differences across case classes) and https://github.com/gnieh/diffson (differences across JSON values).

Comment: You may also want to keep an eye on MUnit https://scalameta.org/munit/

Comment: zio-test's `assertTrue` macro also does something similar.